# Can't install packages because linux images have dependecies with themselves

Tags: apt, dependencies, conda

to fix it I deleted some of the `initrd.img-4.4.0-64-generic` files, leaving the ones leading up to the linux image I'm actually using, to do this I had to navigate to boot in the terminal then `sudo thuner` (this was the bit thata was hard to work out because xubuntu renames thunar file manager) I was then able to run the -f install command and everything seems to be back to normal now. Thanks to everyone who tried to help, communities like these and the collections of knowledge and experience they house are so important.

I'm trying to install `libraw-dev` in order to use [rawpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/) in Python, here's what I get:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libraw-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libraw-dev : Depends: liblcms2-dev but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-66-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-79-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-66-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic (= 4.4.0-66.87) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-signed-image-4.4.0-79-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic (= 4.4.0-79.100) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`apt-get -f install` gives me:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic_4.4.0-79.100_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic_4.4.0-66.87_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running `autoremove` brings up the same error as trying to add a package, I tried using the software updater tool to update the linux-image I think I read somewhere that that might help but theirs not enough space in /boot, and when I try to clear out the old images using [this](http://tuxtweaks.com/2010/10/remove-old-kernels-in-ubuntu-with-one-command/) I get the dependency error again. I've tried removing another program using apt just to test it and again got the dependency error. I was playing around with conda environments making and removing some before is it possible this could have caused it?

I'm using xubuntu, I get `4.4.0-64-generic` when I put `uname -r` into the terminal, thanks for taking the time to read this.

edit:after updating(apologies for the formatting of the outputs, does anyone know why it wont let me do more than one more line as code?):

> AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.

after `-f install` the last part of the output is again (I'd put the whole output but it won’t display it as code and the forum thinks I’m trying to post too many links):

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-79-generic_4.4.0-79.100_amd64.deb 
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic_4.4.0-66.87_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and finally redoing the install as before still gives me the dependency error as before.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but could you please try running `sudo apt-get update`, followed by `sudo apt-get -f install` and then run your original command again, and tell us what happens.

Comment: I've tried what you said, it doesnt seem to have helped unfortunately, thanks anyway though

Comment: Are you still getting the exact same error, or has it changed at all?

Comment: itss exactly the same

Comment: Read the error messages carefully - the packages do not depend upon themselves. Look for the '-extra' and  '-signed' strings to see the difference. Clean out those old kernels if you are not using them.

Comment: I've been trying too clean them out, do you know of a way of removing them that doesn't use apt? all the solutions I've tried so far have failed I think because of this, I'm trying to delete one of the initrd files to free up space in /boot

Comment: What's your Ubuntu release? Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `dpkg-query -Wf '${Status;1} ${Package} \t${Version}\n' linux-image-\* linux-signed-image-\* | sed -ne 's/^i //p'`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Nick Weinberg](https://askubuntu.com/users/546208/nick-weinberg)'s suggestion in the comments fixed the issue for me on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - 64bit:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: where you getting the same error with the images being dependent on themselves?

Comment: confuser already said in the comments that the solution didn't work for them